# (SPLUNK) How to set continuous monitoring of an input file so that graphs get updated with appended data

Tags: splunk

I've uploaded a txt file containing CPU performance data to splunk, set the source type to csv and have created an index. I've been able to generate a report from this.

Data is coming from the txt file correctly under correct index and sourcetype, but problem is the file is constantly appended with new data and the appended data doesn't come up until i add the same file again from data inputs and do the same steps again.

Can someone please help on how to get the data indexed in Splunk as soon as the input file gets updated. From my research, I've found that I need to customize the inputs.conf file, but I have no idea where to start.

Your help would be very much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Specify refresh tag in your dashboard xml. Please find below sample.

```
 https://answers.splunk.com/answers/295137/how-to-auto-refresh-a-dashboard.html
```

Comment: That's not it. The source is constantly being updated, so I need splunk to monitor it and index the file again

Comment: You would see indexed logs on splunk. If you see logs on splunk, that means logs are indexed already. From your dashboard, keep refreshing the panels and see if you are getting updated results. If so refresh option should work.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have selected 'contionous monitor'option for the file you have  uploaded. 
This will populate the logs in splunk automatically when the entries are made in text file